# Populate div with content of external div with rendered html?

Tags: jquery, video

fellas. I'm working on a video portfolio site. There's a video wrapper and underneath there are thumbnails. When you click a thumbnail, it populates the main video frame with a vimeo embed. That works great. But for each video, there needs to be additional info to the side. I've gotten the info to show up when the user clicks the thumbnail but I can't get the info to render as html. It only renders as text.  This is what i'm using to populate the main video frame with vimeo:

```
function show(link) {
    document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = '<iframe src="' + link.href + '" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>';
    return false; 
}
```

and this is what I'm using to populate the info div:

```
$('a').on('click', function(e) {
    $('#divresult').html($(this).text());
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

And [here is the test link.](http://samiandsteve.com/testi.html)

I'm a jquery newb and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: does this work: $('#divresult').html($(this).html());

Comment: that works but it pulls ALL the html content including images. Shaunak's answer below is the perfect solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.text()` gives you plain text while `.html()` gives you htmlstring.

But, using `.html()` on `$(this)` would copy the thumbnail too. So you would need to manipulate the Info.

You can use `clone()` for this,

```
$('a').on('click', function(e) {
    var $info = $(this).clone()
    $info.find('img').remove();
    $('#divresult').html($info.html());
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `.text()` to pull information. That's going to get you plain text and not HTML.

**Change**

```
$('#divresult').html( $(this).text() );
```

**To**

```
$('#divresult').html( $(this).html() );
```

From http://api.jquery.com/text - `.text()` will...

> Get the combined text contents of each element in the set of matched elements, including their descendants, or set the text contents of the matched elements.